# mongodb insert gives wrong _id

Tags: mongodb, insert

I inserted a document to collection poll in the following way:

```
poll.insert({
            'title':title,
            'options':options,
            'votedBy':{},
            'createdBy':theUser,
            'date':date
        },function(err,docs){
            res.redirect('/poll/'+ObjectId(docs._id));
        });
```

From the res.redirect, the _id is "5694e3471baae48402d26196", then when I saw the _id of the document inserted, it is "5694e3471baae48402d26195", exactly 1 difference in the last digit.If I use `console.log(ObjectId(docs._id))` before res.redirect,the id changes by 2 values.Please explain why is it behaving in such manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docs._id is already an ObjectId. When you say ObjectId(docs._id) it considers that as invalid parameter and returns a new ObjectId.

If you are using nodejs, just do 
res.redirect('/poll/docs._id.toHexString());

Comment: Yes, I am using nodejs. Thank you!